# JS RegExp matched entries count

Tags: javascript, regex, count, exec, match

Is it possible to get a count of entries that matched of RegExp in JS?
Let's assume an simpliest example:

```
var pattern =/\bstring\b/g;
var str = "My the best string comes here. Do you want another one? That will be a string too!";
```

So how to get its count? If I try use a standard method exec():

```
pattern.exec(str);
```

...it shows me an array, contains unique matched entry:

```
["string"]
```

there is the lenght 1 of this array, but in reality there are 2 points where matched entry was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

```
var pattern =/\bstring\b/g;
var str = "My the best string comes here. Do you want another one? That will be a string too!";
alert(str.match(pattern).length);
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pTJ5g/1/)